# Is the amount of sand finite?

Tags: minicraft

> ### Note: This is a question about Minicraft. Not Minecraft

I have picked up most of the sand in the desert on the island where I have built myself a home and I am now wondering if it's possible in anyway to "grow" back the desert. I want to have sand spread so I can pick it up again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you dig out all the sand, it will never respawn. You are guaranteed to have at least 100 sand tiles on a map (any map having less is rejected and regenerated).

Here are the minimum amounts of tiles for each level:

- Overworld:

  - Rock: 100
  - Sand: 100
  - Grass: 100
  - Tree: 100
  - Stairs Down: 2
  - Stairs Up: 2 (As determined by the Sky)
- Cave level -1:

  - Rock: 100
  - Dirt: 100
  - Iron: 20
  - Stairs Down: 2
  - Stairs Up: 2 (As determined by the Overworld)
- Cave level -2:

  - Rock: 100
  - Dirt: 100
  - Gold: 20
  - Stairs Down: 2
  - Stairs Up: 2 (As determined by the Cave Level -1)
- Cave level -3:

  - Rock: 100
  - Dirt: 100
  - Gem: 20
  - Stairs Up: 2 (As determined by the Overworld)
- Sky

  - Cloud: 2000
  - Stairs Down: 2

Comment: About the regenerated thing.. Really?? It doesnt just say 'Add more sand' but 'Lets start over again!' ??

Comment: Yeah. I don't know what reasoning Notch had, but I'm betting since regenerating isn't that expensive compared to balancing out all the necessary tiles (Sand isn't the only tile tat has a minimum). I'll edit in all the minimum amounts of tiles